# What does BadImageException mean and how do I fix it?

Tags: c#, dll, .net-core, badimageformatexception, .net-core-2.1

I have a project using .NET Core 2.1 SDK and I want to use a dll on my project.

The Dll use *Pechkin.synchronized* NuGet Package.

I referenced the dll my project create an instance and invoke a method I get `BadImageException`.

How can I use this dll? *Pechkin.synchronized* does not support .NET Core 2.1. Is there a way to use this dll on .net core project?

Comment: Are you sure that the dll and your application are both the same bitiness, i.e. are they both x86, or x64?

Comment: Actually, your question is not "*How can I use this dll*", your question should be "*what does `BadImageException` mean and how do i fix it*"

Comment: @TheGeneral I edit the subject thnx.

Comment: @Nanhydrin I guess the dll is x86 and I build several times my project x86, x64 or anyCpu mode. I try to referance Pechkin.synchronized to my project too but the packed for .net standart not .net core

Comment: That package gives you a dependency on webkit, takes a bunch of unmanaged DLLs.  Which always have a strong bitness dependency.  The github depository for the project shows that author made no attempt at trying to support x64, he hard-coded the DLL dependencies like libeay32.dll in his project.  It needs a patch from you.